# happy number problem in python. how to avoid infinite loop?

Tags: python

this code works for happy numbers only. When inputting a sad number, i get a RecursionError because the function will infinitely loop because base condition will never be met. (the program should return 1 for happy numbers. return 0 for sad numbers). i am having trouble approaching how to incorporate returning 0 for sad numbers.

happy numbers are numbers that if each digit is squared and added together, at some point, it will give you 1. ex: 7-> 49->97->130 ->10->1.
sad numbers are all numbers that aren't happy-- 2, 3, 4..

```
def main():
    usernum= input("enter a number: ")
    happynum(usernum)

def happynum(num):
    result=0
    if num == '1':
        return 1
    else:
        for dig in num:
            result += int(dig) * int(dig)
        happynum(str(result))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "i cannot get it to work"? In what way does it fail to work?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on how to write a high quality question.

Comment: I don't see that you call `main()` anywhere.

Comment: your `happynum` function doesn't actually return anything except for the input `'1'`. You probably want to `return happynum(str(result))` on the last line, as well as to determine what the base case of the recursion is that results in `0` and return that. (I haven't studied the problem so I'm not sure how to handle that.)

Comment: You need to fully define your goal problem, and then give us proper documentation of the error. [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here.  We need to know what a "happy number" is and exactly how your code fails on a particular input.

Comment: i left the the main() call out here, but it is present in my code. this code works for happy numbers. however, when i input a sad number like 5, it will run infinitely. i get a recursionError. I dont know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy numbers will eventually converge on 1, where your base case will catch it. But unhappy numbers enter into a periodic sequence that doesn't end. As a result your recursion will never end. One solution is to keep a list of the numbers you have seen so far. If you seen a repeat you know you are in a loop and therefor started with an unhappy number.

```
def happynum(num, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    result=0
    if num == '1':
        print("happy")
        return 1
    else:
        for dig in num:
            result += int(dig) * int(dig)
        if(result in seen): # been here before
            print("sad")
            return
        seen.add(result)
        return happynum(str(result), seen)

happynum('97') #prints happy
happynum('98') # prints sad
```